# I need help restoring function of tmux after receiving error connecting to /tmp/tmux-0/default (No such file or directory)

Tags: kali-linux, tmux

I am new to tmux I was only using it on my Nexus 6p running Kali nethunter. The reason I used tmux was so I can run the airgeddon script without having a GUI (can't seem to get VNC server to run without freezing phone)
So I took the recommendation from airgaddens GitHub and installed tmux and it works great.
But after rebooting I can no longer get tmux to start.
I did a lot of digging and tried a lot of different things including installing plug-in manager and tmux resurrect but I lack the understanding of how to fix the problem. (error connecting to /tmp/tmux-0/default (No such file or directory)

I ended up trying to apt-remove tmux --purge then reinstall but I fear this may have made things worse.
Please could someone help this poor noob

Comment: Is there no way to completely Purge tmux and start from scratch?

Comment: "error connecting to /tmp/tmux-0/default (No such file or directory)" – From what *exact* command do you get this error? Please [edit] and add this information to the question body.